# Compile Fortran Code With Cross Modules Dependencies

Tags: fortran

I am having problems with some modules dependencies.
Basically, I have three files:

`datatypes_module.F90`,`functions_module.F90` and `main.F90`

The `datatypes_module.F90` contains my datatypes.

The `functions_module.F90` contains some functions which use the datatypes of the `datatypes_module.F90` file.

And the `main.F90` contains the main program which uses both, the datatypes and the functions.

In my head, I need to compile the datatypes first in order to generate the *.mod file.

I am using:

```
    gfortran -c datatypes_module.F90
```

it generates the datatypes_module.mod file.

Now, when I try to compile the functions module with:

```
    gfortran -c functions_module.F90
```

I get an error:

```
    Error: Symbol ‘f64’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

I am not understanding this error as the *.mod file is in the same directory as the functions_module.F90 file.

How can I manage to compile a code with this architecture ?

Thanks

datatypes_module.F90

```
module datatypes_module

    ! Default FORTRAN intrinsic variables.
    use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

    ! Quarter precision integer variable.
    integer, parameter :: i_08 = int8 

    ! Half precision integer variable.
    integer, parameter :: i_16 = int16

    ! Single precision integer variable.
    ! Equivalent to integer(4)
    integer, parameter :: i_32 = int32

    ! Double precision integer variable.
    ! Equivalent to integer(8)
    integer, parameter :: i_64 = int64

    ! Single precision floating point.
    ! Equivalent to real(4)
    integer, parameter :: f_32 = real32

    ! Double precision floating point.
    ! Equivalent to real(8)
    integer, parameter :: f_64 = real64

    ! Extended precision floating point.
    ! Equivalent to real(16)
    integer, parameter :: f_128 = real128

end module datatypes_module
```

functions_module.F90:

```
module functions_module

    use datatypes_module
    implicit none

    contains

        real(f_64) function sum_numbers(a,b)

            implicit none

            real(kind=f_64) :: a
            real(kind=f_64) :: b

            sum_numbers = a + b

        end function sum_numbers 

        real(f_64) function mul_numbers(a,b)

            implicit none

            real(kind=f_64) :: a
            real(kind=f_64) :: b

            mul_numbers = a + b

        end function  mul_numbers

end module functions_module
```

main.F90

```
program main

    use datatypes_module
    use functions_module, only : mul_numbers 

    implicit none

    integer(kind=i_08) :: a = 10
    integer(kind=i_16) :: b = 10
    integer(kind=i_32) :: c = 10
    integer(kind=i_64) :: d = 10

    real(kind=f_32) :: e  = 10.0d0
    real(kind=f_64) :: f  = 10.0d0
    real(kind=f_128) :: g = 10.0d0

    real(kind=8) :: h = 10.0d0

    write(*,*) a 
    write(*,*) b 
    write(*,*) c 
    write(*,*) d 
    write(*,*) e
    write(*,*) f
    write(*,*) h
    write(*,*) g

    write(*,*) mul_numbers(f,f)

end program main
```

++ EDIT #01 ++
Based on the the comments of the users, I manage to compile the code above. In the end, in function definitions, you cannot use the `kind` statement.

Comment: How is the syntax of this ?

Comment: import is useless here. This was just a typo (f64 instead of f_64)

Comment: *"In the end, in function definitions, you cannot use the kind statement."* What dou you mean by this? There is no kind statement in Fortra (there is a kind function) and you can use `kind=` in function definitions. The only problem here was a simple typo.